# Intellisense for QDialog object in Qt Console application

Tags: qt, dialog, intellisense

I'd like to show and then close a dialog after 5 seconds within my main() function in a Qt Console application. Here is my code that works:

Main.cpp:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include "splash.h"
#include <QTimer>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
QApplication a(argc, argv);

// some stuff to do

Splash splash;
QTimer::singleShot(5000, &splash, SLOT(close()));
splash.exec();

// some more stuff to do

exit(0);
//  return a.exec();
}
```

text_console.pro:

```
QT += widgets \
      gui

CONFIG += c++11 console
CONFIG -= app_bundle

DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

SOURCES += main.cpp \
    splash.cpp

FORMS += \
    splash.ui

HEADERS += \
    splash.h
```

The above code complies and works, but I do not get complete intellisense for the splash object (e.g. `setModal()`, `exec()`). What am I doing wrong?

I am using Qt5 in linux.

Comment: What version of Qt Creator are you using? Are you on Windows? Can you post the `Splash` class code? On older versions of creator, this kind of code completion issues were solved ctrl-clicking the header name in the #include ...

Comment: I just edited my question to include OS and Qt version. Your solution actually solved my problem. Thank you. If you change it to an answer, I mark it as answer.